# Java + MySQL or LDAP Server Status

Tags: java, mysql, ldap

How can I check from Java is MySQL / LDAP is running or not?

Comment: Will a simple connection creation and reverting the status do the job for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply attempt a connection. In case the target servers aren't running, you will get, and catch an exception indicating this.

If you then don't want to use the connection, if successful, `close()` it.

Comment: was thinking of the same, but is that the right way to test the connection?